# Most efficient way to read from external accessory input stream and push to s3?

Tags: ios, inputstream, external-accessory

I am trying to read up to max 2MB from an external accessory via bluetooth and its taking a lot longer than expected. We are optimising on the external accessory side of things but I am looking also for a more efficient way to write the data to a temporary file before uploading it to s3 or even better just piping the inputstream straight to s3.

At the moment we have a very simple mechanism which is pretty much based on the EADemo code and aws examples:

```
// low level read method - read data while there is data and space available in the input buffer
- (void)_readData {
#define INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE 1024
    uint8_t buf[INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    while ([[_session inputStream] hasBytesAvailable])
    {
        NSInteger bytesRead = [[_session inputStream] read:buf maxLength:INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        if (_readData == nil) {
            _readData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        }
        [_readData appendBytes:(void *)buf length:bytesRead];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SessionDataReceivedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}
```

And our _sessionDataReceived:

```
- (void)_sessionDataReceived:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    SessionController *sessionController = (SessionController *)[notification object];
    uint32_t bytesAvailable = 0;
    NSData *streamData;

    while ((bytesAvailable = [sessionController readBytesAvailable]) > 0)
    {
        streamData = [sessionController readData:bytesAvailable];
    }

    if (![_fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:_deviceFile]) {
        [_fileMgr createFileAtPath:_deviceFile contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:_deviceFile];
    [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [fileHandle writeData:streamData];
    [fileHandle closeFile];

    NSDictionary *attributes = [_fileMgr attributesOfItemAtPath:_deviceFile error:NULL];
    unsigned long long fileSize = [attributes fileSize];

    if (fileSize == (ourExpectedBytesSize)) {
        [self sendToS3];
    }
}
```

And our sendToS3:

```
- (void)sendToS3
{    
    _s3filekey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/files/%@", user, _deviceFilename];

    AmazonS3Client *s3 = [self s3Client];

    S3TransferManager *tm = [S3TransferManager new];
    tm.delegate = self;
    tm.s3 = s3;

    S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:_s3filekey inBucket:_uploadBucket];
    por.requestTag = @"sendToS3";
    por.filename = _deviceFile;

    [tm upload:por];
}
```

What would be the best way to get and push this data to s3 as fast/efficiently as possible?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to send data to S3 in a background thread.